# Validate Unique - TypeError Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: php, laravel

I have in the User model this method:

```
public function setDocAttribute($value){
    return $this->attributes['doc'] = $this->clear($value);
}
```

The clear method:

```
private function clear(?string $arg){

    if(empty($arg)){
        return '';
    }
    return str_replace(['.','-'], '', $arg);
}
```

Then I have a class User that extends FormRequest with this rule:

```
class User extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'doc' => (!empty($this->request->all()['id']) ? 'required|unique:users,doc,' . $this->request->all()['id'] : 'required|unique:users, doc'),
            ...
        ];
    }
}
```

But the unique part of the rule is not working properly because the doc input have pontuation, so it will compare for example "0043-23.00" with "00432300" and its different so the validation passes. To solve this in the User form request the method all() clear the 'doc' input:

```
public function all($keys = null)
{
    return $this->clear($this->request->all());
}
```

Method clear():

```
public function clear($inputs)
{
    $inputs['doc'] = str_replace(['.','-'],'', $this->request->all()['doc']);
    return $inputs;
}
```

But like this shows an error:

> "TypeError
>   Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, null given".

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missed `return` in the `all` method.

And you can use validation rule unique for a simpler check:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'doc' => [(new Unique('users', 'doc'))->ignore($this->request->get('id'))],
        // ...
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but same error with return like  "       return $inputs['doc'] = str_replace(['.','-'],'', $this->request->all()['doc']);".

Comment: But you should return `$inputs` array.

Comment: Thanks but same issue with return $inputs.